# C# wait and pulse

Tags: c#, java, synchronization

In Java you can wait on every object, so this kind of scenario is possible to program:

Thread A waits on object a

Thread B waits on object b

Thread C notifys on a

Thread A notifys on b

if i use C#'s Monitor, it seems to me that Thread C could only wake b up (or b and a), then how do i make such a scenario possible?

Comment: Usually you'd start with code...

Comment: the question is way more readable when its abstract, at least in my opinion

Comment: What's the equivalent Java code?

Comment: @OfekRon: Quite the reverse, actually. I'm pretty sure you've misunderstood how `Monitor` works in .NET - if you'd produced sample Java code and similar C# code which you *believe* to work differently, we could help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be thinking that because the C# synchronization functions are members of the `Monitor` class, that you need a special `Monitor` instance to use them, in contrast to Java where they are members of the `java.lang.Object` class and available for all objects.

Quite the opposite.  There are no `Monitor` instances at all.  In C#, the functions are static methods, and still work on any object.  The only reason for the `Monitor` class is to prevent `System.Object` from being cluttered with extra members (which would show up in Intellisense suggestion lists, etc).

However, I find that code using `Pulse` usually has hidden race conditions.  There are better ways to synchronize between threads that make writing reliable code easier.

Answer (score 3):

> if i use C#'s Monitor, it seems to me that Thread C could only wake b up

Why? It Thread C is calling `Monitor.Pulse(a)` then that will wake up thread A, just like `a.pulse()` would in Java.

While there are *some* subtle differences, `Monitor.Wait`/`Pulse`/`PulseAll` in .NET are very similar to `Object.wait`/`notify`/`notifyAll` in Java. I strongly suspect that whatever difference you're currently thinking about isn't the case, but it's hard to say without concrete code.

Comment: youre right, i didnt notice the methods were given an object as parameter to wait on.

Comment: @OfekRon: It's worth noticing that you'd have run into that pretty quickly if you'd tried to come up with a complete example for the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse` methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood you correctly, but I don't see any problems. The following code is intentionally simplified, no classes and no declarations for a and b:

```
public void ThreadARunner()
{
    lock(a)
        Monitor.Wait(a); //waits here until thread C pulses, releasing the lock on a
    lock(b)
        Monitor.Pulse(b); //wakes up thread B
}

public void ThreadBRunner()
{
    lock(b)
        Monitor.Wait(b); //waits here until thread A pulses, releasing the lock on b
}

public void ThreadCRunner()
{
    lock(a)
        Monitor.Pulse(a); //wakes up thread a
}
```

For further help, provide more details.
Read [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) for how Monitor works in C#.